# Sufficient condition for a infinite countable or non-countable intersection of open sets is equal to an open set.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $(X,\tau)$ a no discrete topological space. If necessary for an affirmative answer consider a metric space $(X, d )$ or a Banach space $(X, \|\,\cdot\, \|)$. In these cases, the topology $\tau $ would be generated  $d$ or $ \|\,\cdot\, \|$ respectively.

It is well known examples of countable family of open sets whose intersection is not a open set. For example $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}(-1-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n})=[-1,1]$.

> **Question.** There is a suficente condition about a family $\{ \mathcal{O}_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ ( $I=\mathbb{N}\mbox{ or } \mathbb{R}$ ) of open sets in $\tau$ topology that ensures that the intersection is also an open set which is not discrete in $\tau$ topology?

Furthermore, every point $x$ of a metric space $X$ is the intersection of a countable family of balls with radius $\frac{1}{n}$  centered at $x$. If $x$ is not a isolated point then the intersection  $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}B(x,\frac{1}{n})=\{x\}$ is closed. But if $x$ is an isolated point the intersection  $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}B(x,\frac{1}{n})=\{x\}$ is an open set. But this sufficient condition is trivial.

An interesting example is the intersection $\bigcap_{t\in I}A_t$ of a family $\{A_t\}_{t\in I}$ ( $I=[0,1])$  of open sets $A_t$ living in the function space $C^{1}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Usually, it is difficult for the intersection to be open. Consider for example a decreasing sequence of open intervalls $O_n=(a_n,b_n)$ where $a_n$ is increasing and $b_n$ decreasing (and $\sup a_n < \inf b_n$).